# How to change AMI for auto scale on every code ship with codedeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I just have setup autoscale, elastic loadbalancer and codedeploy.

When i ship new source through codedeploy every running ec2 instance is updated with new source as per my requirement.

But whenever new ec2 launch it is using old AMI.

How can i figure out this issue?

I have to create every time new AMI when i ship code?

Comment: i have same issue, what have you done to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeDeploy can be integrated with your Auto Scaling group as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html).

> When new Amazon EC2 instances are launched as part of an Auto Scaling
>   group, AWS CodeDeploy can deploy your revisions to the new instances
>   automatically.

Comment: Hi Mark. I have already install code deploy agent through a user data when create launch configuration. after that i have change some source via codedeploy. So ec2 instance is up to date. but when auto scale create new instance it has code deploy agent installed. but has no latest source which is publish later. I am confuse what is the part of configuration i am misssing.